# ModelMapper mapping enum to same enum returns null

Tags: java, enums, mapping, modelmapper, access-levels

I have an entity, with an enum type field and a DTO with the same enum type and field name.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Gender gender;

    // getters and setters
}

public class UserDto {
    public Gender gender;
}

public enum Gender {
    male,
    female,
    unisex
}
```

I'm using modelMapper by creating a new object **with no additional config**.

But after mapping the dto to entity object, gender is null on the entity object.

Dto object has gender, I've checked that much.

```java
UserModel user = mapper.map(dto, UserModel.class);
user.getGender(); // null
```

Please help me understand the issue.

Comment: could you provide a runnable code of your example ? In particular what is mapper exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `UserDTO.gender` is a public field without a getter. On the other hand `UserModel.gender` is a private field with getter.

ModelMapper seems not to mix field and method accesses so you need to access both sides either by filed or method.

Try to configure your ModelMapper to read/write private fields so not using getters & setters:

```
ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
mm.getConfiguration()
    .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
    .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE);
```

Another option would be to declare your `UserDto.gender` private and have a getter for that.